# Wildfly mysql dependencies not available

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly, redhat, jboss-forge

I'm using `wildfly` and `maven` and I'm trying to deploy a `java ee` application to `wildfly` as well as add a `mysql` database as a `datasource`.

I've added the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar` driver in the `\.wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main` folder aswell as a **`module.xml`** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
     <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar"/>             
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I've also edited the `\.wildfly\standalone\configuration\`**`module.standalone.xml`** file and added the **`datasource`**:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/mySQLDS" pool-name="quizzer" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizzer</connection-url>
    <driver>mysqlDriver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>****</user-name>
        <password>****</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

As well as the **driver**:

```
<driver name="mysqlDriver" module="com.mysql">
    <datasource-class>com.mysql.Driver</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

I'm using [jboss forge](http://forge.jboss.org/) and `maven` to build the project. When I try to **deploy** the application the generated warfile from the project I get the following **error**:

```
Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {"Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"quickdemo.war\".POST_MODULE","jboss.persistenceunit.\"quickdemo.war#mySQLPersistence\".__FIRST_PHASE__"],"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysqlDriver"]}}
```

Finally, this is my [**`pom.xml`**](http://pastebin.com/e0iV6SUw) file and [this](http://pastebin.com/Z9kdDxBw) is the full stack from `.forge\log\forge.log`.

One more strange thing: The `wildfly` welcome screen on `localhost:8080/` says `WildFly 9` is running however console at `localhost:9990/console/App.html#standalone-deployments` (which is where one of the welcome screen links points to) says `10.0.0.Final` and that makes more sense because it's the one I downloaded and installed. I think the other version may be due to the [`Wildfly As`](http://forge.jboss.org/addon/org.jboss.forge.addon:jboss-as) plugin I installed on forge or perhaps they simply forgot to update the welcome screen.

Comment: You should look this example using wildfly10 with javaee7 using mysql github.com/lucasopires/JavaEE7-angularJs

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the driver class.

Use `<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>`
instead `<datasource-class>com.mysql.Driver</datasource-class>`

And its always recommended to have custom modules outside `system` directory

Exact stack trace will be more helpful if you can provide,

Comment: Changed it to `<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>`, still getting the same error. As for the full error stack trace, I'm deploying using the management interface and thats all I'm getting. If I deploy from forge I get `***ERROR*** Deployment failed and was rolled back.`. Where can I read get the full stack?

Comment: Usually it will be stored under directory  ${USER_HOME}/.forge.

Comment: And use mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar not mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar in module. I hope you have the jar in ...com\mysql\main directory

Comment: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar` is in `.wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main`.
I'm using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar` because its the [driver from maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6), should I be using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar `?

Comment: Updated the reference on `module.xml` and I'm using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar` now but I still get the same error

Comment: If possible please post the debug or error log. Run forge in debug mode. And How you are accessing Datasource in project? JPA ?

Answer (score 0):

WILDFLY 10 using mysql 5.7

follow this steps: comment or delete exampleds in standalone.xml

into jboss-cli.bat --connect
after execute command [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)

should be ok

this modified standalone.xml, then add

```
url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
<driver>h2</driver>
<security>
    <user-name>sa</user-name>
    <password>sa</password>
</security>
</datasource> -->
<datasource jndi-name="java:/mysql" pool-name="mysqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wildfly</connection-url>
<driver>mysql</driver>
<security>
    <user-name>root</user-name>
    <password>jdfoxito10</password>
</security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
<xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
</drivers>
</datasources>
```

should look like!

and module.xml put in

\java\server\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main

mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar (come installer mysql-installer-community-5.7.15.0.msi) module.xml

and content from module.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
<resources>
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

and ready, JAVA_HOME should be ok